# CSS3 translate relative to top right

Tags: css, transform

Is it possible to do a CSS3 translate with the origin of the translation being the top right corner? I have tried the following:

```
transform-origin: top right;
transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0);
```

([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justspamjustin/vtn8jmb1/))
but the translation still seems to be happening from the top left.  Is it possible to translate via the top right, bottom left, bottom right etc.?

This image shows the result of the above CSS. (The red box is translated 10px from the top and 10px from the left):

[image]

This image shows the behavior that I want (red box translated 10px down from the top, but also 10px from the right of the grey container).

[image]

I know that I can do this by using:

```
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
```

but my question is: is this possible by using CSS3 translations?

Comment: Looks to be working correctly to me. No matter which corner you translate from, your code will place it 10px right and 10px down. Can you describe what you expected to happen?

Comment: I'd like to translate relative to the top right of the parent element rather than the top left.

Comment: @justspamjustin Your intended behavior is not clear. Perhaps an image or video could help us understand better what you're saying

Comment: @ZachSaucier I guess that what he wants is to have the element positioned right: 0px, in the first place, and then translate3d (-10px, 10px, 0) ... but it's just a guess

Comment: @ZackSaucier I updated the question. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Translate takes every pixel in the rendered element and moves it (in your case, 10px down and 10px left).

It doesn't matter what the `transform-origin` is, because all pixels in the rendered element go through the exact same manipulation.